# What would this small motor be used in?

Tags: motor, identification

I am trying to identify the use of this small motor. I have searched and searched but no luck. Would it be used in an electronic device such as a old VCR? Is it DC or AC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Electric curtains, cassette tape, toy truck... Looks like a brushed dc motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The photo quality is poor but it appears to have drive teeth close to the motor (which makes sense as there is most support from the bearing and least bending moment on the shaft).

The large disc has square teeth with gap = tooth. This looks to me that it is intended for servo positioning or speed monitoring. It looks like about 48 teeth around.

Potential applications are anything in the Sharp back-catalogue that required controlled motion. I have no idea if they sold parts to other OEMs.

> Is it AC or DC?

Almost certainly DC. Look for a permanent magnet and brushes to confirm.

Comment: I have had no luck finding a sharp back-catalogue, any help?

Comment: By "Sharp back-catalogue" I meant consumer goods catalogue. i.e., all the gadgets they made over the years. I suspect that it was not for general sale to other OEMs and that you found a spare for one of their own products. Hook it up to a bench power supply, set the current limit to 0.5 A and wind the voltage up towards 12 V stopping when you think it can't take any more. If you haven't got a bench PSU then wire a 21 W car brake lamp in series as a current limiter. (Or just connect it up to 12 V and see if any smoke comes out!)